# how to remove element in swift array?

Tags: arrays, swift3

I want remove some element in an two dimensional array .
Code:

```
var newlyDataArray = [[CommonItemModel]](){
    didSet{

    for dataArray in newlyDataArray{
        for model in dataArray{
            if model.isSelected == false {
                dataArray.remove(at: dataArray.index(of: model))
            }

        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

but got an error says : the dataArray is an let constant. so I can't change it. so how could I define the `[[CommonItemModel]]` as an let constant?

Comment: your code is like when snake eats its own tail – altering a collection while enumerating it; try not to do so, then the error is going away too.

Comment: do not remove objects while iterating - so try my 2nd solution. Please tell me if it´s working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3 can remove an object by itself like

```
array.remove(object)
```

Also you are able to filter a list and so you don´t need this loop:

```
array = array.filter { $0.isSelected == false }
```

Comment: the second way works for me. but I don't find array.remove(object) in Swift3 .  I don't know why , because objective-c have the method and quite convenience than filer method.